# ¿Cómo controlar la creación de tablas de forma automática desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Resulta que en un problema me piden controlar tablas dinámicas a según se requieran.

El problema radica en que no se sabe cuantas secciones y subsecciones podrian surgir con el tiempo, según cuando se cree una sección a esa sección se le pueda añadir una subseccion y a esa sub subseccion añadirle otra sub sub  subseccion de manera que se pueda llevar el control de lo que se hace en cada mínima parte las secciones padres.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Es esto correcto o es una mala práctica no tener ese control definido?, en lo personal se me complica porque no tengo claro de como podría realizar lo, si el caso fuera diferente y se supieran cuantas subs de cada sección seria mas fácil porque sabría hasta donde tendría que crear las tablas.

De este modo tampoco sabría como relacionar las nuevas tablas con sus claves foráneas.

ejemplo de esquema

```
seccion 1
    subseccion 1
        subsubseccion 1
            subsubsubseccion 1

seccion 2
    subseccion 2
        subsubseccion 2



[![Imagen detallada de como se irían agregando y relacionando las tablas con su tabla padre, para agregarlas podría controlarse con combobox y de ahí agregarlas por su id pero no tengo muy claro de como hacerlo][1]][1]
```

Dando la idea que cada  esquema de arriba es una estructura en cascada en una BD
y que por ejemplo:

Si yo quiero saber si se realizo algún movimiento en la sección 2 lo pueda consultar.

si quiero saber que actividad se hizo en la (seccion 1 -> subseccion 1 -> Subsubseccion1) poder visualizar esos datos.

Pero repito se requiere dinámicamente no se si me doy a entender, no anexo código porque aun no se como empezar. si alguien pudiera aportar una idea se agradecería mucho, o si de plano no se puede, igual se agradecería su explicación.

[image: Anexo imagen de como se irían relacionando las tablas controlados por combobox o no se.]

Comment: Deberias definir por lo menos un ejemplo de las tablas o de las secciones... para tener un contexto claro y no tan general.

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z añadí una imagen, ojalá y pueda servir, agradezco tu apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si todas las secciones tienen los mismos campos, solo añade un campo de seccion_id para relacionar la tabla con si misma.

Ejemplo:

tabla seccion

```
id | nombre_seccion | secccion_id
1  | Primera        | NULL
2  | Segunda        | 1
3  | Tercera        | 1
4  | Cuarta         | 2
5  | Quinta         | 3
6  | Sexta          | 2
7  | Septima        | NULL
8  | Octava         | 7
9  | Novena         | 4
```

El arbol serial el siguiente

```
-1:Primera
--- 2:Segunda (seccion_id: 1)
----- 4:Cuarta (seccion_id: 2)
------- 9:Novena (seccion_id: 4)
----- 6:Sexta (seccion_id: 2)
--- 3:Tercera (seccion_id: 1)
----- 5:Quinta (seccion_id: 3)
-7:Septima
--- 8:Octava (seccion_id: 7)
```

Como podrás ver algunas de los registros tienen como padre, un id de la misma tabla, creando una jerarquia de registros como en el caso de:

```
Primera
   Segunda
      Cuarta
          Novena
```

Para agregar un hijo a Novena, solo tienes que crear otro registro con el id de Novena que seria el id 9, y así con todos los registros, y así dinamizas las tablas.

Los que tienen el valor NULL es porque no tienen un pare y estan de primeros en la rerarquia.

EDITO:

Me tome la libertad de hacerte un test:

Consulta:

```
SELECT padre.nombre nombre_padre, hijo.nombre nombre_hijo, hijo.seccion_id id_padre
FROM secciones padre
INNER JOIN secciones hijo ON padre.id = hijo.seccion_id
```

lanza:

```
nombre_padre   | nombre_hijo | id_padre
Primera        | Segunda     | 1
Primera        | Tercera     | 1
Segunda        | Cuarta      | 2
Tercera        | Quinta      | 3
Segunda        | Sexta       | 2
Septima        | Octava      | 7
Cuarta         | Novena      | 4
```

Comment: Entonces esta opción me serviría si para el esquema dinámico amigo, entonces si quisiera añadirle un hijo al hijo de 9na igual funcionaria verdad, y así ya no necesitaría crear el montón se sub-tablas entonces.

Comment: Exacto... esto lo hace wordpress para crear categorias y sub categorias.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, por tu ayuda me sacaste de un gran apuro. Te lo agradezco!!!